# How can we define a class decorator which allows us to overload the class constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, constructor-overloading

How can we write a class-decorator which accepts the old class as input and outputs a new class such that:

- the old class `__init__` is wrapped in `functools.singledispatch`
- the new class has a `registerfriend` method.
- `registerfriend` takes a callable as input
- `registerfriend` does something like `klass.__init__.register(callable)`

Assume that `__init__` always takes exactly one argument besides `self`

We might want to overload `__new__` instead of `__init__` or overload the `__call__` in the meta-class.

A use case occurs when we have two classes:

1. a class named `Apple`.
2. a class named `Orange`.

The `Apple` class was written with no idea what an `Orange` was.

At some later date, we decide to over-load the `Apple` class constructor so that we can construct an an `Apple` from an `Orange`

```python
def new_constructor(orn:Orange):
    pass

Apple.registerfriend(new_constructor)

orng  = Orange(None)   # meta(Orange).__call__ is registered for type(None)
appul = Apple(org)
```